# Password reset token generation fails

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to create password reset feature in my ASP.NET Core MVC project. The validation process is done by jQuery. The method for this purpose is:

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<JsonResult> ResetPassword(string username, string newPassword)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(username);
        var token = await _userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);
        if(user != null)
        {
            var result = await _userManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user, token, newPassword);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return Json(new { success = true});
            }
            else
            {
                return Json(new { success = false });
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(new { success = false });
        }
    }
```

The problem is that `_userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user)` causes the context to be disposed and the process stops there. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by registering token:

```
builder.Services.AddIdentity<AppUser, AppRole>(options =>
{
    options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;
    options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
    options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 0;
    options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
    options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
    options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
    options.Tokens.PasswordResetTokenProvider = TokenOptions.DefaultProvider;
}).AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityAppContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```